# Javascript and Fusion Table

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have the following controls in my web page. In the first select control, the user should select the column from my fusion table and in the text box that value should be displayed. When apply button is clicked, the map should be rendered and if add condition is clicked, same control should be displayed again.

Can any one refer examples for doing this?

Here is my web page image link:

http://i1248.photobucket.com/albums/hh486/balajisees/pc.jpg

Answer (score 1):

[This example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/in) generates a where statement dynamically and updated a map. Is this what you're trying to do?