# column as a variable

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Is it possible to pass the coloumn name also like a variable.Please edit this code.

```
 var columnname=hhSanitHouseType;
 var operator = ...;
 var textvalue = ...;
 layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry',hhSanitHouseType FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'hhSanitHouseType'" + operator + " '" + textvalue + "'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to ask the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907101/fusion-table-query) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083120/fusiontable-query-for-where) [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023791/fusion-table-column-name-query) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006357/googlemap-api-code-on-dropdown-and-text-box) [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988662/javascript-and-fusion-table) [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006357/googlemap-api-code-on-dropdown-and-text-box).

I already [gave you the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092118/549755) or see [the answer of Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941680/549755). Or am I missing something?